# Check if Class exists through the DOM using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a bunch of pages following the same layout but some of them have a "secondary" navigation bar at the top. When this navigation bar exists I have to push the main content down from the page using `margin-top` in the less.

My issue is I can't find a clean way of doing this just through the DOM.

**sample.html**

```
<!-- The secondary navigation below the header -->
<div class="navigation-row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 text-center">
        <h4> Sample Page </h4>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="row">
    ...
```

**index.html** (inherited template that every page uses)

```
<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="content container-fluid">
    <div ng-class="{'secondary-nav' : document.getElementsByClassName('navigation-row').length > 0}" ui-view="main"></div>
</div>
```

So basically in my main content section I am trying to check if the class `navigation-row` exists on the page (navigation-row is the class for the secondary navbar) and if it does then add the class `secondary-navbar-padding` to the div.

I have tried using [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) which looks like

```
<div class="row" ng-class="angular.element($document).hasClass('navigation-row') ? 'secondary-navbar-padding' : ''">
```

but it didn't work. Is this even possible to do? Am I approaching this incorrectly or if there is a suggestion for a better cleaner way to do this I would be open to do that also.

Comment: Try use `angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.className'))`

Comment: I think you might need to call a function and do all this there since for `ng-class`, you won't have `angular.element` available in the HTML

Answer (score 4):

I think you are only checking if the `document` element itself has that class.

You can count the number of elements with that class like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('navigation-row').length
```

So you could use `ng-class` this way:

```
<div class="row" ng-class="{'secondary-navbar-padding' : document.getElementsByClassName('navigation-row').length > 0}">
```

Comment: So this seems to work if I type

    `document.getElementsByClassName('navigation-row').length > 0`

in the browser console it will give me true if the navbar is there and a false if the navbar isn't there. But for some reason whenever I put it in my ng-class:

    `<div ng-class="document.getElementsByClassName('navigation-row').length > 0 ? 'row secondary-navbar' : 'row'">`

It won't ever use the `true` portion of it. Whether or not I comment out the `navigation-row` portion. But in the console it reads correctly as true or false.

Comment: I think what you have would work with parentheses around the inequality.

Comment: I think your solution works but I figured out why it isn't working for me. I guess I explained my problem incorrectly and I have a layout that is being inherited (`index.html`). I have updated my question. I guess the issue lies in it's checking the document.getElementsByClass name of the template (`index.html`) so by the time it is picked up by the `sample.html` it is automatically false and not setting the class.